# How Redirect when a Promise is Resolved?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying do implement a `onClick()` function that when the user click the Submit button, it saves the information and take the user to another page. I tried a few ways with no success.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

<Button onClick={() => 
  saveUserData(this.props.selectedElement) // the promise is resolving
    .then(<Redirect to='/other_url' />)
  }>
  Submit
</Button>
```

I also tried:

```
.then(() = > {<Redirect to='/other_url' />})
```

Comment: Post your `Redirect` and `saveUserData` code.

Comment: @AdamGold `Redirect` is from `react-router-dom` and the `saveUserData` does not matter in this case, it just connect with my API to send some info, the promise is resolving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect you need to **render** `<Redirect />` to navigate to a new location

I would have done something like this:

```
state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    saveUserData(this.props.selectedElement)
      .then(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }));
  }

  render () {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

     if (redirect) {
       return <Redirect to='/other_url' />;
     }

     return (
  ...

       <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
           Submit
       </Button>

  ...
 )
}
```

Comment: Now it's not working because my redirected page is doing other API calls to render other stuff, so it its reaching a limit of nested updates, but I think your way is the correct one to solve the mentioned issue, thanks for the help!

Comment: glad I could help